# Methods and performance thereof

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

I am about to write a multitude of back-end C# methods for my webpage To update data in a database from 17 controls on my page itself.

Just before I write 17 Methods to handle a update procedure towards my database, I would like to know if it would be more efficient to write 1 huge method to handle all my update scripts for all the controls of my webpage? I am going to use the SQLConnection Object together with SQLCommand to achieve this.

What I am trying to prevent is long-running queries in my webpage because of too many methods (if that is even possible)

By default, If my controls are left empty, no corresponding data (like the Title of a career) in my table within the database must change.

So would it be better to write 17 different methods for my 17 controls? or to Write 1 large validation method to Search through every control's contents and running an update script afterwards?

A little clarification

These 17 methods that I wanted to write for each control will only be called if the corresponding control does not have its default value (so if textbox 5 is empty, then textbox 5's Update method won't be called).

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing the nature of the data, and the likely number of queries required (on average). What I can say is that 17 round-trips to the database will be a lot slower than just one.

Comment: I see my question was a tad ambiguous. I clarified a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably worth making sure it's only one *database* call, but whether it's one method or 17 will make no significant difference at all, if the two approaches actually do the same thing. There may be an *insignificant* difference, but the time spent talking to the database is going to dwarf anything else.

Comment: Drat -- I had the same answer a good 30 seconds before; but someone stopped by my desk and asked a question -- foiled again!

Comment: see, the reason why i wanted to split this into a 17-part operation was that I could validate the controls 1 - by - 1 to ensure that no false data is added to the database. They wont be called all at once, they will only be called if my controls do not have a default value in them (like an empty textbox). So should I still carry on with 1 large method?

Comment: @Eon: It's not really clear what you mean, to be honest. One option is to have one *overall* method which calls another method for each control.

Comment: @Eon : Nothing should stop you from using this method -- just don't make the call to the server more than once.

Comment: 1 large method it is then. Ouch at my poor wrists, because this is gonna be another 500 line method :P

Comment: @Eon: No, no, no. Split the method up into multiple methods - one "coordinating" method which calls the rest. That way you can test them independently, and it'll be simpler to understand.

Comment: I have thought of that, thats why I asked this question. The button on my page will be the caller of these methods to coordinate the values inserted into the textboxes (15 / 17 of the controls are textboxes, some will contain float values which needs converting first, some has character amount limits, and some even need regular expressions to evaluate them).

Comment: @Eon: I don't follow why you'd want to put everything in one giant method then... or why you think that was what I was suggesting.

Comment: now that I think of it, should I rather use a delegate and add these methods to it before calling all of them?

Comment: im still a student/intern at programming . Still need to learn all the curves

Comment: @Eon: I see absolutely no reason to use a delegate here. Just split the method up, have one method which does little but call the others, assemble the results, and call the database.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to only perform one update request to the sql server.  The overhead of communicating to the sql server is going to be the slowest part of an update, if you make one call to a stored procedure on the server this will be 17 times faster than 17 calls to the server.

Answer (score 1):

The overhead of the database will far outstrip the negligible overhead of a method call invocation.

In general, until you have evidence that you need to, don't sacrifice maintainable code for performance.

Note that this is under the assumption that the database workflow is the same for both options!  Making 17 calls to the database instead of one will absolutely hurt performance noticeably.

Comment: so 1 big method to validate all my controls and then building a final script for an update on the table in my database is the best move then?